# Does not work group by function with calculated column in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, case, aggregate

I'm trying to use an aggregate case to create a Pivot table. However, for my created column to represent row number, it shows an Error

> Code: 1056. Can't group on 'rn'.

Meanwhile, if I do the same job manually (by adding the id column to my table it works fine).

Here is code:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (name varchar(128), occupation varchar(128));
INSERT INTO employee VALUES
('Sandra','Gydytoja'),
('Julija','Aktorė'),
('Marija','Aktorė'),
('Martyna','Vadybininkė'),
('Aistė','Mokytoja'),
('Kristina','Mokytoja'),
('Virginija','Mokytoja'),
('Jurga','Aktorė'),
('Justina','Gydytoja'),
('Mia','Vadybininkė');

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY occupation ORDER BY name asc) AS rn,
MAX(case when occupation = "Gydytoja" then name end) AS Gydytoja,
MAX(case when occupation = "Aktorė" then name end) AS Aktorė,
MAX(case when occupation = "Vadybininkė" then name end) AS Vadybininkė,
MAX(case when occupation = "Mokytoja" then name end) AS Mokytoja
FROM employee
GROUP BY rn;
```

Thank You in advance for helping!

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: The result should look like it is presented in the @eshirvana's table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a subquery to populate rn first , then you can use it:

> ```
> SELECT rn,
> MAX(case when occupation = "Gydytoja" then name end) AS Gydytoja,
> MAX(case when occupation = "Aktorė" then name end) AS Aktorė,
> MAX(case when occupation = "Vadybininkė" then name end) AS Vadybininkė,
> MAX(case when occupation = "Mokytoja" then name end) AS Mokytoja
> from ( 
> select * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY occupation ORDER BY name asc) AS rn
> FROM employee
> ) t 
> GROUP BY rn;
> ```
>
> ```
> rn | Gydytoja | Aktorė | Vadybininkė | Mokytoja 
> -: | :------- | :------ | :----------- | :--------
>  1 | Justina  | Julija  | Martyna      | Aistė   
>  2 | Sandra   | Jurga   | Mia          | Kristina 
>  3 | null     | Marija  | null         | Virginija
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26783fc9a4b9d532f7743c6d5b4bc2db)*

Comment: Thank You very much! It seems, what I need (as the result is presented). However, since I'm still a newbie to this, I use MySQL Workbench and once I paste Your code it still shows an error... maybe do You know why? Also what to ask, what this subquery does? I do not understand the usage of it? As it seems like, it "recreates" table by adding additional column, but than, why does not that happen, when I do it directly? Thank You for explaining and spending time on answering!

Comment: @Mindaugas what's the error message? as you see it works in the fiddle. 
but for the subquery , yes , you can interpret it as a table with that extra column

Comment: Never mind, found the error (was missing the semicolon on the previous query... dumb me)! However, for me still, the question remains, why is that needed, and why it does not work doing it directly (without adding subquery)?

Comment: @Mindaugas because in sql engines, group by happens before select statement , also you are not allowed to use window functions directly in group by statements , so the wrokaround this is to use subquery.

Comment: Hm... I see. Thank You for answering and helping!